# Is it possible to listen for Yii events?

Tags: plugin-development, events

I want to listen for Yii events like onBeginRequest and onEndRequest. I've tried the following but nothing happens :(

```
\Yii::app()->onBeginRequest = create_function('$event', 'die ("YO") ;');
```

and

```
craft()->attachEventHandler('onBeginRequest', array($this, 'dieyo'));
```

and

```
craft()->getEventHandlers('onBeginRequest')->add(array($this, 'dieyo'));
```

-

```
public function dieyo($event)
{
    craftdd($event);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did some more testing "onEndRequest" works fine. So I guess onBeginRequest is a loader and/or timing issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yii fires the onBeginRequest event before Craft has had a chance to do any of the plugin bootstrapping / initialization, which is why it's not firing in your plugin.